# Обработчик ошибок для aiohttp сервера

Tags: python, aiohttp

Есть простой сервер:

```py
from aiohttp import web
routes = web.RouteTableDef()

# Error middleware
@web.middleware
async def error_middleware(request, handler):
    print("IN")
    try:
        response = await handler(request)
        status = response.status
        if status == 200:
            return response
        message = response.message
    except web.HTTPException as ex:
        status = ex.status
        message = ex.reason
    if status != 404:
        print(f"{message} with status {status}")
    return web.json_response({'error': message})


@routes.get('/')
async def index(request: web.Request):
    return web.Response(text="Hello, world")


async def init_app() -> web.Application:
    app = web.Application(middlewares=[error_middleware])
    app.add_routes(routes)

    return app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        print(f'Server start!')
        web.run_app(init_app(), host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error: {e}')
```

Нужно для сервера создать обработчик всех ошибок, и данный код ловит некоторые из них, но не все, к примеру он не ловит `invalid HTTP method`:

[image]

Как я могу поймать эту ошибку в моём коде и обработать для красивово вывода в консоль или логов?